# NativeScript with angular Using RadDataForm for a form wizard

Tags: nativescript

Hello I would like to create a wizard form using nativescript with angular 8
I read all the documentation related to RadDataForm and i tried using groups and customizing layouts.
However, it seems that the groups and their elements must stay on the same page.
I did not find examples to make group appear on several pages in a wizzard like style.
Do someone have some idea about it?
Is it possible to create a multi page form wizard using the RaDDataForm?
Moreover, when i create the form I use some switch editors to represent boolean values 
but the text of the label appears on the left of the component and not on top taking space that can not
be used to correctly layout other switchs on the same row. I tried using  editor style to put label on top  but it does not work.  I also tried customizing css in app.css for the editor type and for the property name but nothing happens.

It seems that these settings may not be changed on android.

May someone help me please?
Thanks in advance

```
<TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="retry" displayName="retry" index="0" columnIndex="0">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Switch">
            <TKPropertyEditorStyle tkPropertyEditorStyle labelPosition="Top" backgroundColor="Red"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
            </TKPropertyEditor>
            </TKEntityProperty>
        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="Immediate" displayName="Immediate" index="0" columnIndex="1">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Switch">
            <TKPropertyEditorStyle tkPropertyEditorStyle labelPosition="Top" backgroundColor="Red"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
        </TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>

        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="preask" displayName="Preask" index="0" columnIndex="2">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Switch">
                <TKPropertyEditorStyle tkPropertyEditorStyle labelPosition="Top" backgroundColor="Red"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
            </TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>


        <PropertyEditor[name='Immediate'] {
         font-weight: bold;
         position:top;
         background-color: red;
       }
       PropertyEditor[type='Switch'] {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: red;
       }
```

Comment: Use EntityProperty instead of PropertyEditor to select entity with same and then style the property editor inside.

Comment: does not work. I added these settings in the app.cs file but nothing happens 

EntityProperty [name='Immediate'] {
    font-weight: bold;
    position:top;
    background-color: red;
}

Comment: I guess you are mistaken, you should still style property editor but select entity by name, space property editor to style particular editor.

Comment: can you post an example please?

Comment: EntityProperty[name='Immediate'] DATAFORMEDITORLABEL {
    font-weight: bold;
    position:top;
    border-color: #303F9F;
    background-color: red;
}.  Do You mean this? It does not work